# How keep the values of a fragment components after a fragment was instantiated?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have this method which is called when user click on an item from a list:

```
 @Override
    public void navigateToPackageComponent(int packageIndex) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (formFragment == null) {
                formFragment = new PdfFormFragment(packageIndex, editPendingPackage);
            }           
            fragment = formFragment;

        //...... another instances 

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Even the fragment is instantiated only once in the above method the following onCreateView method from the fragment is called every time.

```
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,       
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdf_form, container, false);
        //....  
        topLayer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
        //.....

        indexDefRootView = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.componentsLayout);
        for (IndexDefView index : indexDefinitions) {
            View indexView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_form_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) indexView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            tv.setText(index.getLocalizedName());
            EditText editText = (EditText) indexView.findViewById(R.id.value);
            editText.setTag(index.getId());
            editTextList.add(editText);

            indexDefRootView.addView(indexView);
            if (editPending) {
                editText.setText(loadValue(index));
            }

            String text = loadValueFromSavedIndexes(index);
            System.out.println(">>>> load indexes " + text);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogS.e(e);
            }

        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

So how can I preserve the values of the fragment if the fragment is not instantiated for the first time.

Best Regards,

Comment: you are looking for a method to store all the values required for instantiating a fragment , Isn't it?

Comment: actually i am looking to skip the fragment update when the fragment was already instantiated but any support is appreciated.

Comment: You can very well instantiate the fragments using an object factory or creational pattern and serialize it and store in the savedInstanceBundle by overriding inSaveInstanceState() method

Comment: I instantiated the fragment without any pattern (see the navigateToPackageComponent method).  I cannot update the instantiate mode.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the late response. You can have a map with package index as key and an array of datatype that you require for instantiating the fragment, like editPendingPackage as the value. If you need not more than one data or int ,in your case other than the package index itself then the value can be only that datatype like int